# How can I display native accents to languages in console in windows?

Tags: python, unicode

```
print "Español\nPortuguês\nItaliano".encode('utf-8')
```

Errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       print "Español\nPortuguês\nItaliano".encode('utf-8')
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

I'm trying to make a multilingual console program in Windows. Is this possible?
I've saved the file in utf-8 encoding as well, I get the same error.

*EDIT
I"m just outputting text in this program. I change to lucida fonts, I keep getting this:
[alt text http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/7312/foreignlangwindowsconso.png](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/7312/foreignlangwindowsconso.png)

I'm just looking for a portable way to correctly display foreign languages in the console in windows. If it can do it cross platform, even better. I thought utf-8 was the answer, but all of you are telling me fonts, etc.. also plays a part. So anyone have a definitive answer?

Comment: Ok I opened, cmd.exe then type chcp 65001
This "changed the codepage"
Now this code will properly display it:
print u"Español\nPortuguês\nItaliano"
with .py file encoded in utf-8 in the editor

Now I must find a way through python to set this codepage automatically.....

Comment: here's [how to do it on Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in Python 2.x you can't `encode` a `str` that has non-ASCII characters.  You have to write

```
print u"Español\nPortuguês\nItaliano".encode('utf-8')
```

Using UTF-8 at the Windows console is difficult.

- You have to set the Command Prompt font to a Unicode font (of which the only one available by default is Lucida Console), or else you get IBM437 encoding anyway.
- `chcp 65001`
- Modify `encodings._aliases` to treat "cp65001" as an alias of UTF-8.

And even then, it doesn't seem to work right.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"Español\nPortuguês\nItaliano".encode('utf-8')
```

The first line tells Python that your file is encoded in UTF-8 (your editor must use the same settings) and this line should always be on the beginning of your file.

Another thing is that Python 2 knows two different `basestring` objects - `str` and `unicode`. The `u` prefix will create such a unicode object instead of the default str object, which you can then encode as UTF-8 (but printing unicode objects directly should also work).

Comment: i'm on windows 7, on properties ->fonts
I only have: consolas, lucida, and raster fonts
None of them display it correctly, i get weird symbols instead.

Comment: Maybe this link might help you: http://blog.i18n.ro/using-unicode-console-output-with-python/

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
# coding=utf-8
print "Español\nPortuguês\nItaliano"
```

You might want to try running it using `chcp 65001 && your_program.py` As well, try changing the command prompt font to Lucida Console.

Comment: And this will only "work" if your console is set to utf-8. Using unicode everywhere and encoding on output is a far more robust solution.