# Python UnicodeEncodeError / Wikipedia-API

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii, wikipedia-api

I am trying to parse this document with Python and BeautifulSoup:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=opensearch&search=rage_against_the_machine

The seventh Item down as this Text tag:

> Rage Against the Machine's 1994–1995
>   Tour

When I try to print out the text "Rage Against the Machine's 1994–1995 Tour", python is giving me this:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)`

I can resolve it by simply replacing u'\u2013' with '-' like so:

`itemText = itemText.replace(u'\u2013', '-')`

However what about every character that I have not coded for? I do not want to ignore them nor do I want to list out every possible find and replace.

Surely a library must exist to try it's very best to detect the encoding from a list of common known encoding's (however likely it is to get it wrong).

```
someText = getTextWithUnknownEncoding(someLocation);
bestAsciiAttemptText = someLibrary.tryYourBestToConvertToAscii(someText)
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you on Windows, by any chance?

Comment: *How* are you printing the text? To a terminal, to a file? Are you concatenating (str1 + str2) anywhere?

Comment: Does [How can I display native accents to languages in console in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3473166) help?

Comment: I am on Windows 7 and I am printing directly to the terminal

Comment: That link suggests to use .encode('utf-8') which does not work. It gives me the same exact error.

Comment: It also tells you that printing UTF-8 to the windows console is tricky. Did you follow the rest of the instructions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display native accents to languages in console in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3473166)

Comment: Setting my console to use utf-8 via chcp 65001 or setting the font to Lucida Console does not change the behavior. I still get the error.

Comment: Not having Windows myself, I have no further hints for you on how to solve this; all I know is that getting UTF-8 to work in Windows consoles is needlessly difficult, and the linked answer is the only information I have for you.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions Martijn. I'll keep trying and hopefully I'll find something. If I do I'll be sure to post the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding it as UTF-8 should work:

```
itemText = itemText.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Normally, Python detects the terminal codec. Encoding blindly to UTF-8 is not going to help here.

Answer (score 0):

**Normally, you should try to preserve characters as unicode or utf-8**. Avoid converting characters to your local codepage, as this results in loss of information.

However, if you must, here are. Few things to do. Let's use your example character:

```
>>> s = u'\u2013'
```

If you want to print the string e.g. for debugging, you can use `repr`:

```
>>> print(repr(s))
u'\u2013'
```

In an interactive session, you can just type the variable name to achieve the same result:

```
>>> s
u'\u2013'
```

If you really want to convert it the text to your local codepage, and it is OK that characters outside this codepage are converted to '?', you can use this:

```
>>> s.encode('latin-1', 'replace')
'?'
```

If '?' is not good enough, you can use `translate` to convert selected characters into an equivalent character as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700859/how-to-replace-unicode-characters-by-ascii-characters-in-python-perl-script-giv).

Answer (score -2):

You may need to explicitly declare your encoding.

On the first line of your file (or after the hashbang, if there is one), add the following line:

`-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

This 'magic comment' forces Python to expect UTF-8 characters and should decode them successfully.

More details: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: The comment only applies to *reading the source code*, and has nothing to do with output encodings.

Comment: This does not change the behavior of the source.