# Print native accents to languages with command prompt of windows

Tags: python, unicode, printing, command-prompt

I am following this example *[How can I display native accents to languages in console in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473166/how-can-i-display-native-accents-to-languages-in-console-in-windows)* but i get an error message every time i run my file.py with the command prompt of windows.

I wish to print

```
print u"Università".encode('utf-8')
```

and the error is:

```
  File "C:\Users\samsung>C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\uni\uni.py", line 270
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:\Users\samsung>C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\uni\uni.py on line 270, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Moreover, adding # coding=utf-8 as the first line i have the following problem

```
Universit├á
```

instead of

```
Università
```

Comment: Did you read PEP 263 like your error message told you to?

Comment: i am honest yes but i did not understand. Sorry.

Comment: The second line of your Python file should be `#coding=utf-8` (assuming you've saved your file in UTF-8; your encoding may vary.)

Comment: Not sure if this can help but have you added this at the top of your file : # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: @Wooble  using your solution I have the posted above (Universit├á instead of Università)

Comment: How did you create this file?

Comment: @freelancer using your solution I have the posted above (Universit├á instead of Università)

Comment: @Gianni have you followed all the instructions of this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3473206/1612326 have you setted your console as in the answer ?

Comment: Give up. Even if you did it right, you wouldn't reliably be able to `print` characters not in your code page to the Windows console. There are serious bugs in code page 65001. It is not worth the effort. Think of something else to do.

Comment: On Python 3, you could [use this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print u"Università".encode('utf-8')
print u"Università".encode('437')
print u"Università".encode('850')
print u"Università".encode('1252')
```

If your system locale is en-US, then the second line (437) will render correctly.

If you now run:

```
chcp 1252
```

then the last line will look good.

That's because the Windows console does not use UTF-8 (and, in general, s*cks at international support)

You can to run this:

```
chcp 65001
```

to set the console to UTF-8 (that's what 65001 means in Windows numeric code pages),
but now Python chokes (2.7, I did not try 3). And that's because Python 2.7 s*cks at international support :-)